# Zsh escape backslash

Tags: zsh

I noticed a while ago already that in zsh, you can get a \ by typing \\ like in bash.

```
> echo \\
\
```

But, there's a strange phenomenon with 4 backlashes in zsh.

```
bash$ echo \\\\
\\

zsh> echo \\\\
\
```

Do you know why ? Is it a bug ?

Comment: Heh, and I realize by posting this that Stackoverflow prints \ whether  you type \ or \\ !

Comment: But it's not the same inside the comments -_-, that's really weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not a bug.  It's just that the echo implementation in these shells 
have a different default settings for interpretation of backslash sequences.

In either shell the command-line parser will remove one layer of backslashes 
converting 4 backslashes to 2.  That argument is then passed to the `echo` 
builtin command.  When echo interprets backslash sequences 1 backslash is 
output for that sequence, if backslash interpretation isn't being done by echo 
2 backslashes will be output.

In either shell's implementation of `echo` the `-e` or `-E` option can be used
to respectively enable or disable backslash interpretation.  So the following 
will produce the same output in either shell:

```
echo -e \\\\
echo -E \\\\
```

Both shells also have shell-level options to alter the default behaviour of 
their echo command.  In zsh the default can be changed with `setopt BSD_echo`, 
to change the default in bash the command is `shopt -s xpg_echo`.

If you're trying to write portable shell scripts, you'd be best served by 
avoiding use of echo altogether; it is one of the least portable commands 
around.  Use `printf` instead.

Comment: Thank makes sense. But now, why does it work to do echo -e \\ ? After reading you, I would think that \ would be sent to echo, which would try to interpret the symbol after it, but there is none. So I would expect it to wait for more data, or return an error. What happens ?

Comment: echo only processes supplied arguments, it doesn't read input so it can't wait for additional data. Any backslash that isn't part of a recognized sequence is simply output verbatim.

Comment: OK. But why does this difference exist ? Is there a situation where you need one and not the other ?